# Deleted process continues creating a file

Tags: php, cron

In my website I had a process which needs to create a file (executed with cronjob). However, I removed both the script and the cronjob, but the file is still created and the process from the cronjob executed. I know this sounds really unbelievable, but is there any way a process can stack in the memory of the server and loop? Can you think of any other reason causing this problem?

Comment: what is your cron's time schedule ? does it run every hour or ?

Comment: just for the shake of clarity or confusion, just remove or rename your file which you have set a cron file and set your cron email to your email if you have not set it yet to make sure which message you are getting in your email from cron side.

Comment: It was set to run every 5 minutes, but, as I explained, it is no longer running

Comment: sometimes what happens as it was set every 5 minutes, the old processes [older crons which were executed before] may be working as well if you have longer code and stuff in that and hence those are yet to be finished to execute full.

Comment: Is there any way I can make sure all old crons are stopped? When I check with crontab -l there are no jobs listed.

Comment: so u mean you have deleted all the cron jobs from your cpanel ? and still you are having this issue ..

Comment: yes ... I'm trying to understand if this is possible ...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/121023/discussion-between-mit-agile-and-dimentica).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had same issue. Process is executed infinity times and code changes, code removal does not help as it seems that process is "caching" your code.

What I have done:

Log in to SSH to server, use `top` command and search for PHP process PID, than use `kill` to terminate this process. ([some source about it](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-use-ps-kill-and-nice-to-manage-processes-in-linux)).

---

To prevent this:

I have created some file on server and inside every loop and just before starting function (I had recursive function) check if file exists (or check for valid content). If not found - do not execute process.

Comment: You saved my life, indeed, old conjobs were still running so in command line I used `killall (my-running-command)`  The source you shared was really helpful